# Предложение правильно составлено?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Сегодняшнее мероприятие проводится совместно комитетами Госдумы и Совета Федерации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [**совме́стно**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/247306/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)
   ***наречие*** качеств.-обстоят. Вместе, сообща.

**Сегодняшнее мероприятие проводится** (кем?) **комитетами Госдумы и Совета Федерации** (как?) **совместно.**

2. [**совме́стно с**](https://all_words.academic.ru/89489/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)
   *кем-чем. **в зн. предлога*** = вместе с кем-либо, чем-либо (*с твор. пад.* Употребляется при указании на лицо или предмет, совместно с которыми производится действие).
   *Действовать совместно с общественными организациями.*

**Сегодняшнее мероприятие проводится** [кем-то] **совместно** (с кем?) **с комитетами Госдумы и Совета Федерации.**

[сего́дняшний, прил.
1. Относящийся к настоящему, текущему дню.
2. Относящийся к настоящему времени, происходящий сейчас.]

Comment: На мой взгляд, исходный порядок слов предпочтителен, поскольку "совместно" (сообща, одновременно кем и кем и т. п.) характеризует прежде всего _действие_, указывая сначала на _множественность_ его производителей ("это совместная работа"), которых затем можно перечислять неограниченно долго. В конце же предложения слово "совместно" создаёт на себе ненужный акцент, мол ясно кем проводится, но главное, совместно, а не врозь. Чтобы такой акцент снять, нужно превратить это слово в уточнение, отделив его пунктуационно.

Comment: Порядок слов зависит от контекста и имеет два значения: (1) сообщение о совместной работе или (2) акцентирование внимания на факте совместной работы. Поэтому в принципе оба варианта возможны.